# Why I don't feel pain when I press the skin on my knee and elbow?

Tags: human-biology

Does the muscle on our knee and elbow have some speciality ? Why are we unable to feel any sort of pain when I pinch it ? I also did it with my Mom and Dad and result was same .

Comment: I think the skin is what you are pinching, and its mostly dead skin. I could really find a valid source though. Sorry

Comment: There are no muscles (except smooth muscle in the skin) under the skin at the knee or the elbow. You are pinching skin, not muscle.

Answer (score 2):

There is several types of nerves in the body. 
Some nerves are specialized in sensing cold or hot temperature, some other to cuts and cell damage and others feel pressure and touch.

The answer to your question is that the nerves in your elbows and knees have less pain detectors and are in fewer number, thus with they are less sensitive.

Here's a funny little poster on BBC: [Can you pinch yourself without it hurting?](http://www.bbc.co.uk/bang/handson/posters.shtml)